# Make some space between function calls in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This is my code

```
function func(){
console.log('run')
}

for(var i=0;i<1000;i++)
func()
```

I want my function to run 1000 times, but 1 second interval between the calls.
I am searching for an helper function for that force the function to not be called more than 1 times in x milliseconds.

I searched in underscore and didn't found.
something like

```
func=_.interval(func,1000)
```

**_.throttle** not helps me. If I will use _.throttle my "func" will not be executed 1000 times.

Thank you.

Comment: And why do you not want to use a setTimeout or setInterval? If you found a function like _.interval, did you check that it does not use setTimeout/setInterval?? Or did you just fail using setTimeout and setInterval and now refuse to work with it?

Comment: What's the real difference between `_.interval(func,1000)` and `setInterval( func, 100 )` besides the naming?

Comment: I want the first execute will be after 1", the second execute will be after 2", So it will takes 1000" to execute. In other words, I want an helper function that force the function to execute no more 1 times in x ms. But it will not ignore any call.

Answer (score 1):

There are many other ways to do it, this is not the prettiest, but:

```
var tick, delay, count, interval, stop;

count = 1000; // 1000 times
delay= 1000;  // 1s between calls

stop = _.after(count,function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});

tick = function() {
    console.log('TICK');
    stop();
};

interval = setInterval(tick,delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then create a helper function:

```
-.interval = function(func,ms){
   setTimeout(func,ms); // I didn't use setInterval because both aren't same
}
```

I cannot imaging why you would want to do something like that, without using more generic `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

With the above declared, you don't need to use `setTimeout` but your so called *helper* function.

Comment: lol... this is exactly what the op did not want. I find this very funny. +1

Comment: It's not helping what you did. Because the func will execute 1000 times in one second! I want the first execute will be after 1", the second execute will be after 2", and so on...